# AngularJs Datapicker ng-model value not bind properly if ng-model is only year

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

AngularJs Datapicker ng-model  value not bind properly if ng-model is only year.

```
Selected date is: {{today}}
```

Comment: here you can use `date` filter also.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
$scope.today = '2010';
$scope.minDate = new Date();
$scope.open = function() {
 $scope.opened = true;
};
//$scope.dateOptions = {
//  startingDay: 0
//};
})
```

.constant('datepickerPopupConfig', {
     datepickerPopup: "MMM d, yyyy",
     closeOnDateSelection: true,
     appendToBody: false,
     showButtonBar: false
    })

.constant('datepickerConfig', {
  formatDay: 'dd',
  formatMonth: 'MMMM',
  formatYear: 'yyyy',
  formatDayHeader: 'EEE',
  formatDayTitle: 'MMMM yyyy',
  formatMonthTitle: 'yyyy',
  datepickerMode: 'day',
  minMode: 'day',
  maxMode: 'year',
  showWeeks: false,
  startingDay: 0,
  yearRange: 20,
  minDate: null,
  maxDate: null
});